# переход по ссылке из Localhost

Tags: php, localhost

Вожможно ли в принципе из скрипта, запущенного на localhost выйти в Интернет? Как то :

```
<a href='http:/mail.ru'>mail</a>    
либо :
<?mail('someone@mail.ru','subject','body');
?>
```

В случае ссылки Денвер пишет, что на локалхосте такой страницы не найдено

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<a href='http://mail.ru'>mail</a>`   вы забыли один слэш. что касается второго варианта скорее всего если почта не шлется у вас не настроен sendmail

Comment: Вот спасибо, и не заметил как пропустил слэш.
По поводу почты - вся почта отправляется на внутреннюю заглушку !sendmail, а где прописать внешний sendmail?

Comment: Если зайти в денвер в \usr\local\php\php.ini и там в [mail function] настроить какой-то внешний smtp к примеру гугловский или вашего провайдера то заглушку в виде: sendmail_path можно закоментировать. Сори у меня не винда но ход дейстивий вижу такой.

Comment: @Deus: если ответ помог, поставьте птичку возле количества плюсов.